# Javascript Input Management

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some problems about jQuery and Javascript and need your help.

I have a field and an "Add" button. Just like,

```
<input type="text" id="txtQ1_1" />
<input type="button" id="btnQ1_1" value="Add" class="add-button" />
```

When I click "Add" button, this code works:

```
contentQ1_1 = '<div class="removable"><input type="text" class="value" value="' + value + '" /> <input type="button" id="remove-button" value="Remove" class="remove-button" /></div>'; 
divQ1_1.append(contentQ1_1);
```

In here, I have no problem about creating text inputs, but I have a limit.

For Example, If added data (contentQ1_1 or another controller) equals to 6, I would like to disable "Add" button. And when "remove-button" clicks, if the value is not greater than or equal to 6, "Add" button have to be visible.

I have tried some counters and use the "removable" class's index value but it didn't make it work.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if($('div.removable').length>=6)
  $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery < 1.6 do this:

```
$('input[type=button]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

using jQuery 1.6+

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", true);
```

try:

```
if($('div.removable').length>=6)
    $('input:button').prop("disabled", true);
```